# scrollview does not work in my layout

Tags: android

I have created a layout called DashboardLayout which is included in another RelativeLayout.

My DashboardLayout is given below

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal.DashboardLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#f8f9fe">
<!--  News Feed Button -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_news_feed"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/place"
    android:text="@string/my_place" />

<!--  Friends Button -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_friends"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/education"
    android:text="@string/education" />

<!--  Messages Button -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_messages"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/bus"
    android:text="@string/bus_time" />

<!--  Places Button -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_places"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/train"
    android:text="@string/train_time" />

<!--  Events Button -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_events"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/auto"
    android:text="@string/auto" />
```

Then above layout is included into RelativeLayout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/home"        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal.MainActivity">
    <include layout="@layout/fragment_layout" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My layout is given below

[image]

After running the scroll view in DashboardLayout doesn't work.After changing the height of DashboardLayout to wrap_content.I got this layout

[image]

Comment: `DashboardLayout`'s height use `wrap_content` instead

Comment: I am changed it but same problm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove these codes from your relative layout

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```